# escape parameters on onclick event doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, innerhtml

I'm atm working on getting a dynamic table into an html page with a button on every table row's first column to display a description of an item(it's an itemlist).

however when setting the innerhtml with an onclick event i am not able to fire an alert .When i want to call another JS function to call the alert and trying to pass an argument in my onclick function it wont do nothing, when trying to escape the quotes nothing works.

### Javascript

```
function showAuctionList(auctionList){
  var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

  for(var i = 0 ; i< auctionList.length ; i++){
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var description = auctionList[i].itemDesc;

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Show Description" onclick="showDescription( description)">';
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= auctionList[i].auctionId;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= auctionList[i].sellId;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= auctionList[i].startDate;
    row.insertCell(4).innerHTML= auctionList[i].endDate;
    row.insertCell(5).innerHTML= auctionList[i].buyNow;
    row.insertCell(6).innerHTML= auctionList[i].minBid;
    row.insertCell(7).innerHTML= auctionList[i].actualBid;
    row.insertCell(8).innerHTML= auctionList[i].itemCat;
    row.insertCell(9).innerHTML= auctionList[i].itemName;
    row.insertCell(10).innerHTML= auctionList[i].itemDesc;
  }
}

function showDescription(desc){
  alert(desc);
}
```

### HTML

```
  <div id="search" style="display:none">
  <button id="searchButton" onclick="


google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showAuctionList).getAuctionList()"> Search </button> <br>
  <div id="mydata">
    <table id="myTableData"  border="1" cellpadding="2">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><b>Auction ID</b></td>
        <td><b>Seller ID</b></td>
        <td><b>Start Date</b></td>
        <td><b>End Date</b></td>
        <td><b>Buy now option</b></td>
        <td><b>Min Bid</b></td>
        <td><b>Actual Bid</b></td>
        <td><b>Category</b></td>
        <td><b>Item Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Description</b></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    &nbsp;<br/>
</div>
```

### gs function call:

```
 function doget(e){
   ...
   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Main').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
 }
```

can this be escaped that description works as an parameter or whats the workaround about the issue?The rest works perfectly fine though

Comment: Provided example is incomplete..How would one create executable environment for your code ?

Comment: description doesn't refer to anything in 'showDescription( description)'. Thus the code fails silently in the background.

Comment: @magreenberg well description contains the string with information about an item. I know that description doesnt refer to anything thats my problem , i want to pass the variable description in the onclick event as an parameter to call the alert method

Comment: @DavidBizer just concatenate the string together with the + operator. onclick="showDescription( "+description+")"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. As description seems to be a `string` value you need to `surround` it with `qoutes`.

```
row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value = "ShowDescription"  onclick="showDescription(\'' + description + '\');">';
```

Comment: Just to be more accurate, you don't need to escape the double quotes inside single quotes.

Comment: In that case, to be consistent, you need to escape other quotes too ( type="button" value = "ShowDescription")

Comment: @MairajAhmad thank you. I tried it however it didnt work , nothing happened. if i Call showdescription on onclick without a parameter it works fine. The description parameter is also correct.

Comment: @DavidBizer please check now i have updated the answer.

Comment: @TareqMahmood i removed the escape of double qoutes.

Answer (score 0):

You need not escape if use this code:

```
row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Show 
Description" onclick="showDescription(this.getAttribute(\'description\'))">';
row.cells[0].firstChild.setAttribute('description', description);
```